# libpng library - write data to row_pointer variable

Tags: c++, arrays, libpng

I am trying to write a monochrome image to PNG file using `libpng` library. [PNG specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#4Concepts.PNGImage) says that you can use grayscale type, since I do not need shades I want to use only grayscale, without alpha channel. So, the `color_type` parameter is `PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY`.

I am having trouble to figure out how to write data from array of pixels to `row_pointer`. So that I can use `png_write_image(png, row_pointer);`.

If I have image pixels as array of bytes `byte imagePixels[25] = {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0};`. This should represent image that is 5x5 pixel dimension. Pixel with value 1 should be black - `#000000`, and pixel with value 0 should be white - `#FFFFFF`.

In `libpng` [library specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt), it states that `row_pointer` is a array of rows. For my `imagePixels` variable array should be array of the five elements - `row_pointer[5]`.

How do I write pixels from `imagePixels` to `row_pointer` array? I can not figure it out how to write data to `row_pointer` array.

Definition of `row_pointer` is:

```
typedef unsigned char png_byte;
typedef png_byte * png_bytep;

png_bytep *row_pointer;
```

Thanks for any kind of help or suggestion.

Edit:

Code is:

```
row_pointers = (png_bytep *)malloc(sizeof(png_bytep) * m_height);

for (int y = 0; y < m_height; y++) {
    row_pointers[y] = (png_byte *)malloc(png_get_rowbytes(png, infoPng));
    row_pointers[y] = (png_bytep)&(imagePixels[y * m_widht]);
}
png_write_image(png, row_pointers);
```

Comment: What have you already thought of?

Comment: I think I have figure it out. I have edited post. Since here, code is not properly formatted. And it works. Since I am not experienced with C++, is this code OK? Or is it wrong? I have looked at this [example](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html).

Comment: It is close but it will leak memory. Unfortunately I am not sure what help I can give you other than writing the code for you or directing you to a C++ tutorial.

Comment: "How do I write pixels from imagePixels to row_pointer array?" indicates that you don't understand pointers which are a basic concept in C or C++. If you did understand pointers but were confused about libpng, maybe I could answer that, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: I know that I have to use `delete[]` at the end, in the for loop for every row, since I used `malloc()`. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: The concept of what a pointer is and what `malloc` does, probably...

Comment: It is not `delete[]()` it is `free()`, since it is `malloc()`, and not `new()`. I always confuse that. And I can see with a debugger, that there is a memory leak. Now I have to figure how to fix that. Thank you for a feedback, appreciate it.